# How do I remove GNOME in my Linux System(Red 7) ?

Tags: linux

How do I remove GNOME in my Linux System(Red 7) ? 
I wanna install KDE for some testing.

Comment: You can have multiple desktop environments installed at the same time.

Comment: Theoretically, you can install multiple DEs and select the one you want at login.  Theoretically, you can also replace one DE with another.  In practice, it can be a mess, especially with certain DEs.  GNOME and KDE include extensive peripheral stuff, and hook into all kinds of places.  You are much better off creating a different installation using the iso that already has KDE integrated.